# How to filter records of people who have a birthday between two dates based on their birthday using Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I would like to query in my database people who have a birthday between a start and end date. The field is stored with Date in the database, so it would need to select the anniversary disregarding the year. I tried to use functions like extract, to get the day and the month, but when the start day is greater than the final day no record is displayed. Does anyone have a solution for this without a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore the year, then you need to extract the months and days and compare separately:

- month is start month and day is equal to or larger than start day
- month is larger than start month and smaller than end month
- month is end month and days is smaller than or equal to end day

This would give you this query:

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        extract(month from people.birthdate) as birthmonth, 
        extract(day from people.birthdate) as birthday, 
        * 
    from people) a
where a.birthmonth = :startmonth and a.birthday >= :startday
or a.birthmonth > :startmonth and a.birthmonth < :endmonth
or a.birthmonth = :endmonth and a.birthday <= :endday
```

Note that I used named parameters for clarity, even though Firebird itself doesn't have them. You will need to replace this with positional parameters, unless your connection library can do this for you.

If you want to provide an actual start and end date as a parameter, then you may need to do some extra work.